# How to validate a user from deleting records from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a booking system which allows users to view, edit, and delete records. The system currently allows users to delete records at any time. However as it is a booking system, so users should only be able to delete records 48 hours prior to the booking date and it should restrict users from deleting records within 24 hours of the booking date. Is there some sort of function that I will need to include?

This is my current code for deleting records:

bookings.php

```
   echo "<td><a href = 'delete.php?id=".$row['booking_id']."' onclick='return          

   confirmation()'> Remove </td>"; 


      <script type="text/javascript">

        function confirmation()

  {

        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel booking")){
             location.href='delete.php';

           }

           else {

            return false;


           }
         }
```

```
     Delete.php 

          $id = $_GET['id'];

             $query1="DELETE from bookings1 where booking_id='$id'";

                  $results = $mysqli->query($query1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your table structure, but it should look like this:

```
DELETE from bookings1 where booking_id='$id' AND booking_id IN (SELECT booking_id FROM bookings1 
WHERE BookingDate >= DATEADD(HOUR, -48, GETDATE())
  AND BookingDate <  DATEADD(HOUR, -24, GETDATE())
```

Also change

`location.href='delete.php';`

to

`location.href='delete.php?id=".$row['booking_id']."'; return false;`

otherwise $_GET is empty

Comment: my table structure is booking_id, BookingDate, Timeslot

Comment: I have tried this method but it does not delete anything from the database

Answer (score 0):

You can add date column to your records in database and then before delete check how much time left to possibility to delete.

```
$yourEntry = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from bookings1 where booking_id='$id'"));


//Checking difference between two dates (current and your entry date)       
$diff = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) - strtotime(''.$yourEntry[day].' '.$yourEntry{hour].'');

//this is for less than 30 seconds, change for your value
                if($diff < 30){
                    $problem = TRUE;
                }



        if (!$problem){

//your code where there is not a problem with time. In my code if more than 30 seconds. 

         }
```

Comment: My table consists of the following fields which are Booking_id, bookingdate, timeslot

Comment: @RohanRehman how your bookingdate looks like? Its date with time or just date?

Comment: so add one more field with time. Set date to `Y-m-d` and time to `H:i:s`. My code should work with this fields.

Comment: were would i place the DELETE statement

Comment: @RohanRehman Place it in `if (!$problem){  //here your code  }` statement

Comment: should i replace the line   strtotime(''.$yourEntry[day]  to  strtotime(''.$row['BookingDate']  as i would need to retrieve dates and times from the database ?